# How to clear apple webdata on the iPad programatically?

Tags: ios, pdftron

How to clear apple webdata on the iPad programatically?

I'm running a native app using pdftron to convert html to pdf using this command.

```
[PTConvert convertHTMLStringToPDF:dataString baseURL:nil paperSize:pageSize completion: ^ (NSString * pathToPDF) {...}];
```

However, after running the aforementioned code the memory increases and there are a lot of applewebdata appearing.

[image]

If you can't see the image, you can download it here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/52rkg2bdjxx5pld/error_screenshot.png?dl=0

Comment: Is there a simple way to remove all the additional applewebdata:// ?

Comment: the picture attachment does not appear for me. Can you re-try adding that.

Comment: @Ryan, i've just re-upload the image and upload it to dropbox as well